# NGINX Install Failing on Ubuntu 22

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to install NGINX on Ubuntu 22, but the installation is failing.

In short, this is what happens after running apt install nginx:

```
chown: invalid group: ‘root:adm’

dpkg: error processing package nginx-common (--configure):
 installed nginx-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter:
 libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter depends on nginx-common (= 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1); however:
  Package nginx-common is not configured yet.
```

I have posted the full log here: https://privy.ninja/?8e46dc038517fa0e#8uwC1JwN9EbHufZxdt9RqJ94eGfzeSvUyvRWUkEJLPcJ

Comment: https://askubuntu.com is a more suitable place for such.

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed this error. Open the file

```
~$ sudo nano /etc/group
```

and add the line below

```
adm:x:4:syslog,suzy
```

after the sys group.